# Objects in ExpandoObject, how to check if any object contains a "false"

Tags: c#

I need help with "Objects in ExpandoObject". I want to check i any of the objects inside the ExpandoObject has a value of "false".

My ExpandoObject looks like this:

```
                var projects = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

                object listObject1 = new
                {
                    ProjectURL = string,
                    ListItemID = 1,
                    UserAdded = true
                };
                projects.Add("Project" + 1, listObject1);

                object listObject2 = new
                {
                    ProjectURL = string,
                    ListItemID = 2,
                    UserAdded = true
                };
                projects.Add("Project" + 2, listObject2);

                object listObject3 = new
                {
                    ProjectURL = string,
                    ListItemID = 3,
                    UserAdded = false
                };
                projects.Add("Project" + 3, listObject3);
```

Comment: What are the reasons of not using `Dictionary<string, Project>` ?

Comment: What have you tried so far? Also, your code will not compile, this `ProjectURL = string` assignment is not valid

Comment: Is there a reason you're not just using a normal C# class?

Comment: I am using this for an azure function and i am sending the ExpandoObject object back as a response. Thats the reason i am using a ExpandoObject.

Comment: No, that's not a valid reason for using an `ExpandoObject`, you should still use a concrete class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not too sure why you want to do this (perhaps this is an X-Y problem), but you could write a helper method to return all properties of a particular type for an object:

```
public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> PropertiesOfType<T>(object obj)
{
    return from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
        where p.PropertyType == typeof(T)
        select new KeyValuePair<string, T>(p.Name, (T)p.GetValue(obj));
}
```

Then you can iterate through all the objects in your ExpandoObject dictionary to find any that contain a `bool` property with a `true` value:

```
foreach (var item in projects.Values)
{
    if (PropertiesOfType<bool>(item).Any(property => !property.Value))
        Console.WriteLine($"{item} has a false bool.");
}
```

Compilable console app:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Dynamic;
using System.Linq;

namespace CGS
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main()
        {
            var projects = new ExpandoObject() as IDictionary<string, Object>;

            object listObject1 = new
            {
                ProjectURL = "string",
                ListItemID = 1,
                UserAdded  = true
            };
            projects.Add("Project" + 1, listObject1);

            object listObject2 = new
            {
                ProjectURL = "string",
                ListItemID = 2,
                UserAdded  = true
            };
            projects.Add("Project" + 2, listObject2);

            object listObject3 = new
            {
                ProjectURL = "string",
                ListItemID = 3,
                UserAdded  = false
            };
            projects.Add("Project" + 3, listObject3);

            foreach (var item in projects.Values)
            {
                if (PropertiesOfType<bool>(item).Any(property => !property.Value))
                    Console.WriteLine($"{item} has a false bool.");
            }
        }

        public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<string, T>> PropertiesOfType<T>(object obj)
        {
            return from p in obj.GetType().GetProperties()
                where p.PropertyType == typeof(T)
                select new KeyValuePair<string, T>(p.Name, (T)p.GetValue(obj));
        }
    }
}
```

Output:

```
{ ProjectURL = string, ListItemID = 3, UserAdded = False } has a false bool.
```

---

If you want to print out the names of all the bool properties that are false, you could change the loop to:

```
foreach (var item in projects.Values)
{
    foreach (var boolProperty in PropertiesOfType<bool>(item))
    {
        if (!boolProperty.Value)
            Console.WriteLine($"bool {boolProperty.Key} is false.");
    }
}
```

which outputs:

```
bool UserAdded is false.
```